# CSS Dropdown menu and padding (gap) problem

Tags: html, css, frontend

thank you in advance for answering this thread.

We have created a dropdown menu for our web-page but we are having a small issue with regards to the padding.

Please find the code below. Also find attached the reset we have used (reset.css) in case there is something related.

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dexeus Rep</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/styles/reset.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="nav-bar">
        <div class="nav-items">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">LINK 1</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1.2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1.3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1.4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1.5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1.6</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1.7</a></li>   
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>

<style>

.nav-bar {
    background-color: black;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3.325em;
}

.nav-items {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.nav-items ul {
    display: flex;
    color: orange;
}

.nav-items ul li {
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    height: 3.325em;
    background-color: black;
}

ul li:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}

ul li ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 1px;
    top: 3.325em; /* same as nav-bar height */
    /* height: 18em; */
}

.dropdown li{
    position: relative;
}

ul li:hover > ul, ul li ul:hover {
    visibility: visible;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 18.5em;
}
</style>
```

`

RESET:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/*

  Con este reset vamos a resolver:
     Unificar el uso de Custom Properties
     Problemas de box-model más generales
     Problemas con imagenes, vídeos e iconos svg
     Problemas con tipografías y etiquetas input en formularios
     Unificar la tipografía de todas las etiquetas de una web

*/
/* Aquí definimos las Custom properties */
:root {
  --negro: #393939;
  /* Tipografía */
  --tipo-principal: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  --tipo-secundaria: Verdana;
}

/* Las adaptamos al modo oscuro */
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --negro: #ececec;
  }
}
/* Opcional */
/* Configuramos si un usuario ha activado el modo alto contraste. (WD) */
/* Opcional */
/* Desactivamos los animations en el caso de que el usuario haya configurado el modo sin animation */
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  * {
    -webkit-animation: none !important;
            animation: none !important;
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
  }
}
/* Reseteamos los margin y paddings de todas las etiquetas */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* Evitamos problemas con las imagenes */
img, picture, video, iframe, figure {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  /* opcional */
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
  /* opcional */
  -o-object-position: center center;
     object-position: center center;
}

/* Reseteamos los enlaces para funcionar como cajas... */
a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}

/* ... excepto los que se encuentran en párrafos */
p a {
  display: inline;
}

/* Quitamos los puntos de los <li> */
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

/* Configuramos anclas suaves */
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/* Desactivamos estilos por defecto de las principales etiquetas de texto */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, span, a, strong, blockquote, i, b, u, em {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

/* Evitamos problemas con los pseudoelementos de quotes */
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}

/* Configuramos el texto que seleccionamos */
::-moz-selection {
  background-color: var(--negro);
  color: var(--blanco);
}
::selection {
  background-color: var(--negro);
  color: var(--blanco);
}

/* Nivelamos problemas de tipografías y colocación de formularios */
form, input, textarea, select, button, label {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
      -ms-hyphens: auto;
          hyphens: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
  /* opcional */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
}

/* Reseteamos las tablas */
table, tr, td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* Evitamos problemas con los SVG */
svg {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  fill: currentColor;
}

/* (Probándolo, no usar en producción) En el caso de añadir una  */
/* p svg{
  display: inline;
  width: initial;
} */
/* Configuramos la tipografía para toda la web */
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: var(--tipo-principal);
  color: var(--negro);
  /* opcional */
  line-height: 1.4em;
  /* opcional */
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
      -ms-hyphens: auto;
          hyphens: auto;
  /* opcional */
  font-smooth: always;
  /* opcional */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* opcional */
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

[image: padding problem]

The problem is that we have applied right and left padding to the first list elements in order to center the text (LINK1, LINK2, LINK3) so when the dropdown menu appears, left padding is somehow creating a gap (red line in the picture) and the dropdown menu is not in line with the originator.

Probably there is a better way to create the dropdown menu but, as we are learning from scratch, would be great to have an explanation for this specific case even if a better solution is proposed.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with positioning, you should understand how CSS positions work.

In your case, you need to relate the dropdown menu to container, which is here "li", so what would you do:

You give the container: ".nav-items > ul > li" a position of relative
then the ".dropdown" a position of absolute:

```
.nav-items ul li {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: max-content;
}
```

Comment: This was it. Realizing how important is to define the relative/absolute elements when going deep in the cascade. Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the padding from the li and give it to the  instead, and give the main ul class "main-dropdown" just to give it some space on the left, you can remove it if you want, like this:

css:

```
/* new css */
      ul.main-dropdown{
        margin-left:1rem;
      }
      ul li a{
        padding: 1rem;
      }
```

html:

```
<ul class="main-dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">LINK 1</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1.2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1.3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1.4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1.5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1.6</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1.7</a></li>   
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
            </ul>
```

and remove the 1rem padding given to the li (the commented ones)

```
.nav-items ul li {
          color: white;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          font-size: 1em;
          font-weight: 600;
          /* padding-left: 1em;
          padding-right: 1em; */
          height: 3.325em;
          background-color: black;
      }
```

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change a few lines of CSS and do in good format using class names to identify tags. It's not only helpful to target tags, it's also helpful for your site's score and accessibility.

```
ul li ul{
   padding-left: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

```css
.nav-bar {
    background-color: black;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3.325em;
}

.nav-items {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.nav-items ul {
    display: flex;
    color: orange;
}

.nav-items ul li {
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    height: 3.325em;
    background-color: black;
}

ul li:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}

ul li ul.dropdown {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 1px;
    top: 3.325em;
    left: 0;
    /* same as nav-bar height */
    /* height: 18em; */
}

.dropdown li{
    position: relative;
}

ul li:hover > ul, ul li ul:hover {
    visibility: visible;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 18.5em;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-bar">
        <div class="nav-items">
            <ul>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">LINK 1</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Link 1.1</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Link 1.2</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Link 1.3</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Link 1.4</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Link 1.5</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Link 1.6</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Link 1.7</a></li>   
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">LINK 2</a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

if you want to increase dropdown width then you can use

```
ul li ul{
   width: your size;
```

}